# String manipulation & algorithmic complexity

Tags: c, big-o, string.h

Have written 2 implementations of a program that should copy words to an output buffer and print the information out. I'm looking to optimise my program wrt operation time (algorithmic complexity).

```
/*cat implementation*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char command_string[2][70] = {
  "Henry",
  "Julie",
};

int main()
{
    char output_transmit_buffer[255];
    int counter = 0;
    while (1)
    {
      char *command = command_string[counter];
      strcat (output_transmit_buffer, command);
      printf ("%s\r\n", output_transmit_buffer);
      //clearing output buffer
      memset (output_transmit_buffer, 0, sizeof (output_transmit_buffer));
      if (counter == 1)
      {
          return 0;
      }
      counter++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
/*copy implementation*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char command_string[2][70] = {
  "Henry",
  "Julie",
};

int main()
{
    
    char output_transmit_buffer[255];
    int counter = 0;
    
    while (1)
    {
    char *ptr = output_transmit_buffer;
    strcpy(ptr, command_string[counter]);
    ptr += strlen(command_string[counter]);
    printf("%s\r\n",output_transmit_buffer);
    
    memset (output_transmit_buffer, 0, sizeof (output_transmit_buffer));
    if (counter == 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    counter++;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Which implementation is better? Is there a better implementation for MCU specific applications.

Comment: The first one has UB due to calling `strcat` on indeterminate buffer contents. Apart from that, the only difference is that the second one calls `strlen` unnecessarily.

Comment: The examples do not make sense to me. There is no need to copy the strings to the buffer, they can just be printed directly.

Comment: Both make no sense at all. What is `memset` for? To keep CPU busy? The code does nothing. you can simple `printf` the array elements.

Comment: Very strange loop control too. Why not use the obvious and more readable `for` loop?

Comment: Bad design: you have a ```while(1)``` and ```int counter = 0;``` Then doing stuff, checking with ```if (counter == 1)``` statement and incrementing ```counter```. Do instead ```int counter = 2;``` and ```while(counter--)```

Comment: Made the example a bit more basic the need to having an output buffer is so I can add multiple string messages before printing the string. For the example I've only added one string and not multiple. 
The reason for memset is to clear the buffer before copying the next string into the buffer. Would there be a better way to do this ?

Comment: Why do you need to clear the buffer *after* you use it? It doen't need clearing at any time.

Comment: Okay I see; in this application this output_buffer would be the string i'd use the output buffer ;then transmit through a UART buffer. I would always just clear the buffer once transmitted. Now i can see I wouldn't need to this from the comments.

Comment: For an UART buffer you'd typically just copy the data straight from the source into the hardware buffer with no go-between. Depending on how large hardware buffer there is in the UART peripheral. Anyway, all of this string handling code does no good in that context.

Comment: okay that makes sense; what would you do is the payload message is larger than the hardware buffer ?

Comment: "*Which implementation is better?*" Well, you know your own metrics. Which one was better when you ran them and compared the outcome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strcat (output_transmit_buffer, command);` is a bug since you didn't initialize the destination buffer. `strcat` expects a null terminated string as input, unlike `strcpy` which just writes to memory no matter what was stored there before. So you need to do `char output_transmit_buffer[255] = "";` in order to use `strcat`.

As for efficiency, both versions are quite naive. There is lots of room for improvement:

- In this specific case you actually know the size of the strings at compile-time, since they are string literals. So you need not call `strlen` at all. `"Henry"` is an array with size `sizeof "Henry"`, which is 5 bytes + 1 null terminator = 6 bytes.
- Calling `memset` over and over to clear the whole memory is pointless. In case you were to use  `strcat`, you only need to write a null terminator to the first byte `output_transmit_buffer[0] = '\0'`.
- You can save memory by turning the 2D array into an array of pointers instead: `const char* command_string[] =`. Now only as much memory as is occupied by the string literals are used. It should be `const` to make it read-only. On a MCU, `const` means the data ends up in flash instead of RAM which is generally what you want to save RAM.

---

However, what you actually want to do is none of this, but to transfer some strings over UART...

In case all the UART stuff is embedded into your `printf` implementation (like the termios lib or similar) then just print directly, with no middle man. However, using `printf` on embedded systems (or systems in general) is very expensive, so if you are truly looking to increase performance you'd write directly to the UART driver without the burden of the bloated `stdio.h`.

Code to be used on an actual MCU might look something like this:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

#define SIZEOF_ARRAY(arr) (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr))

const char* command_string[] = {
  "Henry",
  "Julie",
};

const uint16_t command_size[] = {
  sizeof("Henry") - 1,
  sizeof("Julie") - 1,
};

void UART_Tx (const uint8_t* data, uint16_t size)
{
  /* 
    Pseudo code for some generic UART hardware peripheral.
    SR = status register, DR = data register
    UART_SR_TX is some TX ready flag
  */

  for(uint16_t i=0; i<size; i++)
  {
    UART_DR = data[i];
    while((UART_SR & UART_SR_TX) == 0 )
    {}
  }
}

int main()
{
    for(uint16_t i = 0; i < SIZEOF_ARRAY(command_string); i++)
    {
      UART_Tx((uint8_t*)command_string[i], command_size[i]);
      UART_Tx((uint8_t*)"\r\n", 2);
    }
}
```

Note that `sizeof` returns an integer of type `size_t` which is what's commonly used in hosted systems. In small embedded systems, we typically micro-manage sizes of variables though, so I used `uint16_t` instead, which will result in better code on 8 or 16 bit MCUs. If all strings are shorter than 256 bytes you can even use `uint8_t`.

Answer (score 2):

This is another way, it completely avoids the expensive call to `printf` (which BTW is probably far more time consuming than the string copying/appending and memory clearing altogether).

It also replaces the complicated `while (1)` logic with a straight forward `for` loop as well as it eliminates the useless `memset`.

```
int main()
{
  char output_transmit_buffer[255];

  for (int counter = 0; counter < 2; counter++)
  {
    strcpy(output_transmit_buffer, command_string[counter]);
    strcat(output_transmit_buffer, "\r");  // puts automatically appends a '\n'
    puts(output_transmit_buffer);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The call to `strcat` is not ideal, you could replace the `strcpy` and the `strcat` altogether. Get inspired from the other answer.

OT: Be aware that `output_transmit_buffer` may overflow if there are many command strings.

Answer (score 1):

Both implementations have room for optimization. For MCU specific applications you should minimize unnecessary operations and optimize memory usage.

In you current implementations, `strcat()` has a time complexity of `O(n+m)`, whereas, `strcpy()` and `strlen()` both have a time complexity of `O(n)`. And you are clearing the output buffer after each iteration, which is not needed.

You can directly copy element from source to destination as below, although the copy makes no sense in your code (but it might be the case that you are using it some where else and you have just posted it as an example).

```
char *src = command_string[counter];
char *dst = output_transmit_buffer;
while (*src != '\0') {
   *dst++ = *src++;
}
*dst = '\0';
        
printf("%s\r\n", output_transmit_buffer);
```

Also there is an issue with your `counter` athe you have to fix.

**Comparison:**

`*dst++ = *src++` is efficient for small strings or when you know the exact number of characters to copy and it is commonly used in situations where memory and processing resources are limited, such as in embedded systems.

`strcpy()` typically performs well for larger strings or when the length of the string is unknown.

Comment: Yes it's for the example. What size would be considered a large string ? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You can add that the very expensive `printf` can be avoided by adding the `\r\n`  explicitly to the output buffer and just call `puts`.

Comment: That `while` loop is just a poor man's `strcpy` though. There's probably no need to hack it out manually like this and no reason to believe that your manual version performs better. Unless perhaps the OP has to stop and wait for some UART Tx status flag between every byte, then it might make sense.